# How to post and retrieve data in url in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, url

I want to post input data to a particular URL and also receive its response back and display the response data in view, Can anyone suggest me how to implement this with sample code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please download any JSON example from github & check it with your own

Comment: You can use ASIHTTPRequest API, hope this will help you

Comment: I would suggest not using `ASIHTTPRequest` as it is no longer in development and support has stopped. You might want to have a look at [`AFNetworking`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method for retriving data using the url:

```
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: 
          yourURL];
```

Here `yourURL` is of type NSURL. It can be formed like:

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://www.example.com";
NSURL *yourURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
```

This is a synchronous method hence it will block the UI, so you need to call it in another `thread` or using `dispatch_async`

This [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5) may help you: